# Why using @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) in Spring JPA and OPTIMISTIC LOCK can be added by @Version only?

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, jpa, locking

We need to use @Version to implement the optimistic lock so by using @Version the hibernate will control very thing then Why @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC) is used ?

What is the advantages and disadvantages of the following code ?

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, UUID> {

```
@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)
UserEntity findById(UUID id);
```

}